# Create Line charts with last 10 entries in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, charts, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet where I want to create a Line chart that contains only the last 10 entries. I have created the Line chart but it is giving me all the entries from the sheet that I don't want Line chart that I am able to create

Here if you can see I am getting all the entries, But I want only the last 10 entries.

And my X-axis will show the Dates with an interval of two i.e the first date will be 24/10/2020 2nd will be 26/10/2020 and the third 28/10/2020 so on.

How to achieve this please let me know.

please find the sheet link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17rmBv1VekMumNq6TZ62vksemGIQzfZmZT7duuDp_bSs/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SPARKLINE(QUERY(B2:B, "offset "&COUNTA(B2:B)-10))
```

[image]